# Use PayPal payment method in the website like airbnb

Tags: drupal, paypal

I am building a website like airbnb style. It's a marketplace for host to post spare room for rent and for student to search to book.

To simplify the payment process, I decided to use PayPal payment.

The payment process would be like this:
1. student books a room and pay by PayPal
2. Money goes to website PayPal account
3. When student checks in, website releases money to host PayPal account

Of course, if student cancel the booking, website has to do refund

Overall the process is quite simple. Just wondering what kind of method of PayPal should I apply? PayPal chained or PayPal Website Service?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing something close to escrow; PayPal chained payments will not do what you want (with time delays and logic/potential exception cases between the chained payments). I would recommend using one of the "normal" PayPal payments inbound and some form of payout API outbound. You still have many choices to evaluate (website standards/express checkout/adaptive/REST/Braintree and more on the front end; Masspay/adaptive/PayPal Payouts on the back end). Look at the specific features of the products (and their integration styles) to decide.

Comment: Thanks for your expertise. Because most transaction will be international, escrow is not the as popular as PayPal which is more adopted worldwide.